# HDIV : looking for HDIV tld

Tags: jsp, struts-1, hdiv

Where I can download the HDIV tld (hdiv-html.tld, hdiv-html-el.tld, hdiv-logic.tld..) for Struts 1?

The documentation say to replace Struts tld (struts-html.tld, struts-logic.tld..) by HDIV tld in the web.xml

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find them in github.
For example for 2.1.13 release:
https://github.com/hdiv/hdiv/tree/2.1.13/hdiv-struts-1/src/main/resources/META-INF

Hope it helps!
Gotzon Illarramendi (HDIV Team)

Comment: Thanks for this response.
                     Just a question: 
my application is using struts 1.2.9 and when I add this dependency
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hdiv</groupId>
   <artifactId>hdiv-struts-1</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.12</version>
</dependency>

Maven add the following jars: 
struts-taglib-1.3.8
struts-tiles-1.3.8
struts-el-1.3.8

But when I add this dependency:
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.hdiv</groupId>
 <artifactId>hdiv-struts-1.2.9</artifactId>
 <version>2.0.4</version>
</dependency>

There is no additional jar.
Which dependency should I add in this case ?

Comment: You can see the dependencies in the pom.xml file: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hdiv%7Chdiv-struts-2.0.9%7C2.0.4%7Cjar Keep it in mind that 2.0.4 is an outdated version of HDIV.